# Frank can't touch a textField with tag

Tags: ios, testing, cucumber, bdd, frank

I have a UITableViewCell, and it was made up with one UITextLable and one UITextField
This UITextField without placeholder and accessibilityhint 
I have to write my feature file touch this UITextFeild by tag.

```
When /^I touch the (\d*)(?:st|nd|rd|th)? text field$/ do |ordinal|
    ordinal = ordinal.to_i
    text_field_selector = "textField tag:#{ordinal}"
    touch (text_field_selector)
end
```

With this step definition, frank(cucumber) raised the error message said that

```
could not find anything matching [textFeild tag:2]
```

And I've changed my code into:

```
When /^I touch the (\d*)(?:st|nd|rd|th)? text field$/ do |ordinal|
    ordinal = ordinal.to_i
    text_field_selector = "textField tag:#{ordinal}"
    frankly_map (text_field_selector, 'becomeFirstResponder')
end
```

Now, frank finally not raise any error message and marked as the test step as passed, **but** I was expecting that when come to this test step, keyboard would come up and stay their waiting for user to input text.
Actual result was the keyboard flashed a bit, and quickly disappeared. Nothing can be inputted.

This is weird and I'm not sure what's this about.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know frank but you can catch a parameter in console in Cucumber by using `ask` method. Something looks like this:

```
When /^I touch the text field$/ do
    ordinal = ask("Which field number?").to_i
    text_field_selector = "textField tag:#{ordinal}"
    touch (text_field_selector)
end
```